# pandas dataframe boolean indexing with multiple conditions from another df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to identify the rows between 2 df which shared the same values for some columns for the SAME row.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{'energy': 'power', 'id': '123'}, {'energy': 'gas', 'id': '456'}])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([{'energy': 'power', 'id': '456'}, {'energy': 'power', 'id': '123'}])
```

df =

```
   energy   id
0  power  123
1    gas  456
```

df2 =

```
   energy     id
0  power    456
1  power    123
```

Therefore, I'm trying to get the rows from df where energy & id matches exactly in the same row in df2.
If I do like this, I get a false result:

```
df2.loc[(df2['energy'].isin(df['energy'])) & (df2['id'].isin(df['id']))]
```

because this will match the 2 rows of df2 whereas I would expect only power / 123 to be matched

How should I do to do boolean indexing with multiple "dynamic" conditions based on another df rows and matching the values for the same rows in the other df ?

Hope it's clear

Comment: Looks like an inner merge: `df.merge(df2)` ? of course you can select the common keys to join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pd.merge(df, df2, on=['id','energy'], how='inner')
```

Comment: Yes that works like this indeed, if you want to do both standard Boolean indexing and merge you need 2 lines instead of 1 but it works great I thought there would be another option but let’s keep it like this then. Thanks